# When importing a mnemonic phrase into a phantom app, the wallet addresses do not match

Tags: wallet, phantom, typescript, phantom-wallet, seed

I tested a code example for generating a mnemonic phrase and restoring a wallet using a mnemonic phrase from the [official Solan documentation](https://solanacookbook.com/references/keypairs-and-wallets.html#how-to-generate-a-mnemonic-phrase) and a question arose.

```
const mnemonic =
    "pill tomorrow foster begin walnut borrow virtual kick shift mutual shoe scatter";
  const seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync(mnemonic, ""); // (mnemonic, password)
  const keypair = Keypair.fromSeed(seed.slice(0, 32));
  console.log(`${keypair.publicKey.toBase58()}`); 
// 5ZWj7a1f8tWkjBESHKgrLmXshuXxqeY9SYcfbshpAqPG
```

but if i import this secret phrase in phantom app, the wallet address will be different (AWjbG5SH5VEay5ksZbGHHgJhYRhM1rsN5Z538cfFvs4a).
How can I make sure that when importing into phantom the address is the same as when creating the wallet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case someone encounters the same problem, I will leave an answer to my question.
The problem is that phantom find first key derivation along the path m/44'/501'/0'/0'.
To get a wallet with the same public key as in phantom you need to use the following code from [official documentation](https://solanacookbook.com/references/keypairs-and-wallets.html#how-to-restore-a-keypair-from-a-mnemonic-phrase):

```
import { Keypair } from "@solana/web3.js";
import { HDKey } from "micro-ed25519-hdkey";
import * as bip39 from "bip39";

(async () => {
  const mnemonic =
    "neither lonely flavor argue grass remind eye tag avocado spot unusual intact";
  const seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync(mnemonic, ""); // (mnemonic, password)
  const hd = HDKey.fromMasterSeed(seed.toString("hex"));
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const path = `m/44'/501'/${i}'/0'`;
    const keypair = Keypair.fromSeed(hd.derive(path).privateKey);
    console.log(`${path} => ${keypair.publicKey.toBase58()}`);
  }
})();
```

P.S.: someone wrote that if you top up your account, it will be higher in the list of keys along the derivation paths and the phantom will find it. But I haven't checked it.

**UPD:**

From the [official phantom app docs](https://docs.phantom.app/resources/faq#how-does-phantom-import-wallet-addresses):

> **How does Phantom import wallet addresses?**
>
> When importing addresses from an existing seed phrase, Phantom will scan for 20 addresses in
> each of our three supported derivation paths (bip44change, bip44, and
> a deprecated path), for a total of 60 addresses. For the convenience
> of the user, Phantom will filter this list of addresses down to
> wallets that have ever had signatures (i.e. have ever been used).
> Phantom will then sort this filtered list based on how many signatures
> each wallet has had plus the amount of lamports it currently owns.